# Trigonometry limit - finding the correct identity to solve the exercise

Tags: trigonometry

Hello I have an exercise that I can not continue.
I think we should use one of these trigonometric functions, but I can not find any identity.
Would appreciate help.

[image: Exercise]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: `1/Sin[x] - Cot[x] == Tan[x/2]`

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\cos\left(\frac x2\right)}=\lim_{x\to0}\tan\left(\frac x2\right)=0.$$